# Is Kalinag supposed to be good or bad? How are Yuma and Kalinag linked?

Tags: far-cry-4

I have seen Far Cry 4 game walkthrough videos in YouTube. I have some doubts regarding the role of Kalinag.

When the player first plays as Kalinag (in the first Yogi mission), he kills Rakshasas (the bad guys) and finally frees a bell whose sound protects the region later (its sound kills Rakshasas). So here, Kalinag is considered good. But later, in a fight with Yuma (who is linked with Rakshasas), Ajay somehow fights with Kalinag and kills him. Here, Kalinag is shown as being sided with Yuma (who is bad). Can someone explain how Yuma and Kalinag are linked?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if these count as spoilers so I'm tagging them anwyay -

> The Kalinag you play in the thangka missions is a hallucination; you're experiencing his story as told by the thangkas. (Trippy, huh.) He was a Kyrati warrior sent to find Shangri-la.

_

> The Rakshasas Ajay goes up against in the jail are probably actually just regular guards - he is on drugs administered by Yuma.

_

> The Kalinag Ajay fights against is Yuma; once again, at that point he is on drugs.

There sure is a lot of fun with drugs in this game.

Answer (score 1):

Kalinag is seen as a great hero, for finding and exploring Shangri-La. Yuma is portrayed as Kalinag because of her strange obsession with finding the mythical place.

Answer (score 0):

It's my speculation that Kalinag and the Rakshasha are linked between the civil wars of Kyrat. Kalinag may Represent the Golden Path because they're the good guys, and Rakshasha represent the Royal Army.  However with further research I found another speculation that it is switched. Kalinag said that he was sent by the king and the king in Kyrat is none other Pagan Min. And since the Rakshasha disturbed the peace of Shang Rila it looks like the Rakshasha is represent the Golden Path since Pagan Min refers them as terrorists.

Answer (score 0):

Well I know its an old thing , but here's My answer,

a kalinag is a warrior (not kalinag himself , a kalinag warrior I said yes)

Kalinag warriors in far cry 4 for example are :

Ajay 
Yuma
And the Royal Army Hunters

To become a kalinag warrior , you need to know the of the legendary kyrati warrior kalinag, and need to experience it by this thangka, and you obtain his skills, kalinag is neither good or bad because its not really clear who's he against the golden path or the royal army, I think Shangri LA has nothing to do with the civil war but that's also unclear.. Because kalinag had an armored elephant and a white tiger as allies, 
And elephant stands for golden path & royal army stands for the tiger, so I guess he was kinda on both sides , he's just a warrior that saved Shangri LA from demons not golden path or royal army, but then again its just so unclear